# Issue with Passport-Local within a Mongoose.save

Tags: javascript, rest, mongoose, passport-local

I am working with the following code;

```
router.post('/register', function(req, res) {
      User.register(new User({ username : req.body.username }),
          req.body.password, function(err, user) {
          if (err) {
              return res.status(500).json({err: err});

        }
      if(req.body.firstname) {
        user.firstname = req.body.firstname;
      }

      if(req.body.lastname) {
        user.lastname = req.body.lastname;
      }

      user.save( function(err, user) {
        passport.authenticate('local')(req, res, function () {
          return res.status(200).json({status: 'Registration Successful!'}); 
        });
      });
  });
});
```

It produces the following;

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("59a631ff29e0a506c81032b3"),
        "salt" : null,
        "hash" : null,
        "username" : "admin",
        "admin" : false,
        "lastname" : "Last",
        "firstname" : "Test",
        "__v" : 0
}
```

The salt and hash are generated from the passport.authenticate('local'). If I exclude the user.save (function(err, user) {...}); code around the passport.authenticate, It does not update the lastname or firstname part BUT the salt and hash DO get updated.

I have searched this forum for a similar issue; reviewed Passport (http://passportjs.org/docs), and Passport-local github (https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local) for possible solutions but have not found a similar issue or solution.

Any suggestions would be awesome.

Comment: Addendum: Passport.authenticate returns 401 Unauthorized when inside the user.save(function(err, user) {...});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much research, Here is a code example that resolves the issue that I was having. First Name, Last Name, Salt, and Hash are updated properly with it.

I am still not sure why the original code would throw a 401 / Unauthorized error when calling the passport.authenticate from within the user.save.

```
 router.post('/register', function(req, res) {
    User.register(new User({
                            username : req.body.username,
                            firstname : req.body.firstname,
                            lastname : req.body.lastname,
                          }),
        req.body.password, function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).json({err: err});
        }
        passport.authenticate('local')(req, res, function () {
          return res.status(200).json({status: 'Registration Successful!'});
        });
    });
});
```